# Installed Ubuntu 11.10, getting hard disk health warnings

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

I'm getting hard disk health problem warnings...

When I click the "examine" button the disk utility pops up.  None of my drives are reporting any major issues, and the very first drive doesn't even have a SMART button.  I don't really care if one of the drives is crashing, I've got everything backed up, but I just want to know how to stop these god forsaken message boxes from popping up randomly. I have already gone into the Disk Utility and checked "do not notify me if this drive is failing" on all of them except the one that doesn't have the SMART button.

I've googled about as much as I can for one day.

Answer (score 2):

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/38281/disk-utility-pop-up-so-many-times-and-too-many-at-a-time-above-10-pop-ups

maybe some bad blocks?

```
badblocks -n -v /dev/sdx
```

where /dev/sdx is the device name of your harddrive

via http://bredsaal.dk/checking-a-harddrive-for-bad-sectors-on-ubuntudebian